# number of linear boolean function with XOR

Tags: combinatorics

For x, y ∈ {0, 1}n
, let x ⊕ y be the element of {0, 1}n obtained by the component-wise exclusive-or of
x and y. A Boolean function F : {0, 1}n → {0, 1} is said to be linear if **F(x ⊕ y) = F(x) ⊕ F(y)**, for all
x and y. What is the number of linear functions from {0, 1}
n
to {0, 1} ?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly $2^n$. They are the *parity functions*, i.e. the elements of the orthogonal Fourier basis used in [Boolean Fourier analysis](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~ryanod/?p=279); defined as
$$
\chi_S(x) = \bigoplus_{i\in S} x_i
$$
for $S\subseteq [n]$.

To see why, you can follow the outline of and do the exercise linked above, which precisely amounts to showing this fact (and, additionally, discusses implications of the result in property testing.)